# Why does this insert statement throw a sql exception by $25

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to insert data from a DataTable in c# visual studio into a table in a sqlite database. After building the insert statement using my DataTable it comes out as this...

```
insert into Records('Ship Code', 'Sail Date', 'Component Name', 'Guest First Name', 'Guest Last Name', 'Guest ID') values (OK,8/4/2018,Arcade $25,john,doe,1111111);
```

And throws this exception when trying to execute it...

> SQL logic error near "$25": syntax error

I understand it's a syntax error but i dont understand why it is.(all variables are currently using nvarchar)

Comment: encapsulate your varchar values in single quotes like you did for field names

Comment: I would expect this SQL code to throw a variety of syntax errors.  Are you *sure* SQLite uses single-quotes for column names and *no quotes at all* for string values?

Comment: The dollar sign is being interpreted as a parameter.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Column names should be in double quotes, btw. Single quotes are for strings, double quotes for identifiers that have to be quoted.

Comment: Also, you *really* want to use one of the [timestamp formats supported by sqlite date and time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) - it'll save a lot of trouble the moment you want to do anything with them like sort results by date.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now, i was just using nvarchar to test i will change the data types and code it to prevent sql injections, idk why i couldnt realize the values werent encapsulated, happens i guess

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into Records("Ship Code", "Sail Date", "Component Name", "Guest First Name", "Guest Last Name", "Guest ID") values ('OK','8/4/2018','Arcade $25','john','doe','1111111');
```

Gotta get your quotes right

Comment: Thanks! i missed it because the statement ran through and didnt throw the error until the $25 part but i understand where i went wrong now

Comment: Yeah the quotes are needed for values where there is a whitespace. Otherwise the parser will take the space to mean that the value is done and will look for the next comma. If it finds anything after the whitespace except a comma it will throw for syntax because it doesn't know what to make of it

Answer (score 2):

The best/safest way is to use parameters.

```
string query = "insert into Records('Ship Code', 'Sail Date', 'Component Name', 'Guest First Name', 'Guest Last Name', 'Guest ID') values (@ShipCodes,@SailDate,@ComponentName,@GuestFirstName,@GuestLastName,@GuestID)";
```

From there, how to populate the parameters is well documented. This way, you don't need to worry about single quotes or double quotes, etc. But most of all, you don't need to worry about [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If I were doing a code review and someone tried to check in an INSERT statement w/o using parameters, I'd make them re-do it! :)